# How do I stop processing filters in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

There's an extension for the contact form 7 plugin for WordPress where I can hide certain form fields, given different conditions (like an "other" field which is hidden until a select option is set to "other"). Unfortunately, if one of those fields is marked as required, an error pops up saying the field is required, even though the user never saw the field!

Unfortunately, Contact form 7 is set up with irreversible field invalidation: once the field has been invalidated, there's no way to re-validate it, and the form submission fails. Since CF7 is so extensible, I need a solution that will cover all validation plugins that use the CF7 validation hook.

remove_filters() doesn't work because I only want it to apply to one field, not all of them. Removing the filter would break the validation for all fields, and I don't want that.

Is there any way to attach a function to a hook that will "abort" that hook, making it stop processing more filter functions for only this instance of apply_filters()?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post at http://blogs.ntm.org/stephen-narwold/2016/10/04/how-to-stop-processing-filters-in-wordpress/, here's what I came up with. We need to set the internal array pointer of `$wp_filter['this_filter']` to the end.

```
add_filters('example_filter', 'my_stop_processing_filters_func', 2);
function my_stop_processing_filters_func( $in ) {
    // Stops filters of this tag from being applied after the current priority level is finished
    global $wp_filter;
    if ( $in['skip-me'] ) {
        // using current_filter() allows one function to be used for multiple filter tags if necessary
        end( $wp_filter[ current_filter() ] );
    }

    // never forget to return the filtered variable!
    return $in;
}
```